# How to change value in Android Swipe View Tab Layout?

Tags: android

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/
I've read and try to code a project like this link.
After that, I try: In tab "Top rate", I change the string "Design Top Rate Screen" (in the page) by "1". After that, I choose tab "Game", I want the string in this page will be "2", and I return to tab "Top rate", the string will be "3". So, when I swipe, the value of the string of this tab will be equal the value of the string in previous tab increase by 1. So, I want to ask: How to do that?
I'm Vietnamese, my English is not good, I hope everybody understand this question.
Thank you.